# Make div take the remaining height after another div take its height below it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sidebar where year is displayed in the bottom and list of links on the top.

1. The *year* text should stay in the bottom and its height should be `auto` not absolute values (like 30px, 1em, 10% etc.)
2. The top links should remain inside the remaining height (screen height - height of *year* text).
3. When the links height exceeds, scrolling should be provided.

I have successfully achieved the first 2, but not the 3rd. When the links height exceeds, the *year* hides from the screen.

I have used `table` to achieve what I specified. (I could have used `display: table`; just being lazy here)

[image]

I want to achieve this using only CSS, no JavaScript.

```css
/* Some styles */
.side-bar table {
 color: #fff;
}
.side-bar-links {
 background-color: #48c;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
.side-bar-links li:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.side-bar-links a {
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.side-bar-links a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.year {
 background-color: #338;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 5px 15px;
}

/* Positioning */
.side-bar {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
.side-bar table {
 height: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}
.side-bar table tr:last-child td {
 height: 1px;
}
.side-bar table td {
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="side-bar">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="side-bar-links">
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 5</a></li>
       </ul>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="year">
   <b>2016</b>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a thousand times easier if you give the year element a fixed height. Then you can do `.sidebar-links { height: calc(100% - [height of year element]); overflow-y: scroll; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS and see if it works:

```
.side-bar {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the *year* does not remain in the bottom of the screen. I want scrolling only in the top links, not in the whole side-bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have something that determines the maximum height your container is going to be.  Then you can handle overflow.  I've modified your code a bit to change to a div layout and set up the overflow on the container.  I believe this is what you're after.

**The example in the snippet has a fixed height, so you may need to open it in full screen to see the whole example ('Run code snippet' - then 'full page').**

You could also use percentages for heights to avoid using a fixed height.

```css
/* Some styles */

.side-bar-links {
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: #48c;
  padding-top: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.side-bar-links li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.side-bar-links a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side-bar-links a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.year {
  background-color: #338;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Positioning */
.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="side-bar">
  <div class="side-bar-links">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="year">
    <b>2016</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<html><head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
/* Some styles */
.side-bar table {
    color: #fff;
}
.side-bar-links {
    background-color: #48c;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.side-bar-links li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.side-bar-links a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.side-bar-links a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.year {
    background-color: #338;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: auto !Important;
    width: auto;
}

/* Positioning */
.side-bar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
.side-bar tr:first-child{height:100%;}
.side-bar table {
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:110px;
}
.side-bar table tr:last-child td {
    height: 1px;
}
.side-bar table td {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="side-bar">
<table>
 <tbody><tr>
  <td class="side-bar-links">
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&gt; Link 5</a></li>
       </ul>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="year">
   <b>2016</b>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>




</body></html>
```